# how can i host react app in IIS web server?

Tags: reactjs, iis, deployment, web-hosting

How can i host `reactjs` app in IIS webserver?

I used `npm run build` and replaced the file into the server and create new site which refers to those file.

also i add the binding all IP to port 80 using * sign.
but not worked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After we run the below command, the output will create a new folder called “build” inside the project which contains production build. We could host the project by copying these files to the root directory of the IIS website, the website root folder should be able to be accessed properly by the anonymous account, and therefore we should grant IUSR account full access to the folder if it is not the default website.
[image]
[image]
After adding the web site binding in IIS binding module,
[image]
We could access the website properly by using the below address.

```
http://localhost
```

Besides, if we adding certain routing features (multiple components) in the react application, we have to install the IIS URL Rewrite extension.
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
After a successful installation, we need to create a web.config file containing the below content under the root directory of the IIS website.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Is this possible without the URL Rewrite extension?

Comment: I had the same problem, but with your help, the problem was solved. Thank you. I have problem with subdomain name. I Put Files inside folder name "home" and web.config is outside with <match url="/home/.*" /> It's not working