# Ive deployed my React app on IIS, it works fine but returns a 404 error when i refresh on other pages besides root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iis

Ive read around and everyone is saying that you need a web config together with the build files. Does anyone have resources on how i can write the config.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, you need more information to analyze the error, I suggest you enable failed request tracing, it will provide the key error and warning.

Comment: Follow this URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63365558/how-can-i-host-react-app-in-iis-web-server

Comment: Does IIS redirect all requests to the index file?

Comment: @jabaa no it justs throws an error

Comment: But it has to redirect it. You have to configure an URL rewrite.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i host react app in IIS web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63365558/how-can-i-host-react-app-in-iis-web-server)